# HTML5 strokeRect - Does the width include lineWidth

Tags: html5-canvas

Messing with strokeRect, the width seems to be sharing the overall width so a rect with a line thickness of 100 and a width of 200 would really be 300 width including the line. Is this correct or am I missing something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `lineWidth` will add 50% of its width to each of the sides of the path itself.

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

ctx.lineWidth = 100;
ctx.strokeRect(50, 50, 200, 200);

ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.strokeRect(50, 50, 200, 200);
```

```html
<canvas width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Comment: Ok cool. Thanks a bunch. I couldnt find anything documenting this and always worry im just crazy.